# Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy

Tags: unity, google-play-services, google-play, admob

I made a game in Unity with admob  integration, and I published it on the Google Play store.

After 2 days I got a mail from the Play store mentioning a policy violation (reproduced below). I l researched the issue and updated a privacy policy document on my app, then resubmitted the game.

It came went live, but then I got the same mail from the Play store again and they removed it.

From the beginning onwards my ads are also not showing in game, but the test ad is working fine.

Can you tell me what mistake I made and how I can fix it?

Message from Google:

> Notification from Google Play about Green Puzzle Truck
>
> Google Play Support
>
> Hi developers at **** **** Studio,
>
> After review, "my game name" , package name, has been removed from
> Google Play due to a policy violation. This app won’t be available to
> users until you submit a compliant update.
>
> Issue: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section
> 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement
>
> Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when
> the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information.
> We’ve identified that your app collects and transmits the Android
> advertising identifier, which is subject to a privacy policy
> requirement. If your app collects the Android advertising ID, you must
> provide a valid privacy policy in both the designated field in the
> Play Console, and from within the app.
>
> Next steps: Submit your app for another review
>
> Read through the Usage of Android Advertising ID and User
> Data policies, as well as the Developer Distribution Agreement, and
> make appropriate changes to your app. If you decide to collect
> sensitive user information, be sure to abide by the above policies,
> and include a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's store
> listing page and within your app.
>
> Make sure that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program
> Policies. Additional enforcement could occur if there are further
> policy violations.
>
> Sign in to your Play Console and submit the update to your app.
>
> Alternatively, you may opt-out of this requirement by removing any
> requests for sensitive permissions or user data.
>
> If approved, your app will again be available with all installs,
> ratings, and reviews intact.
>
> If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this removal may have been in
> error, please reach out to our policy support team. One of my
> colleagues will get back to you within 2 business days.
>
> Thanks for helping us provide a clear and transparent experience for
> Google Play users.
>
> Regards,
>
> The Google Play Team

Answer (score 1):

You must implement something for GDPR if you're shipping in the EU. Your customers need to be able to opt out of the use of tracking IDs and have an option to **delete** any existing tracking info you have.

I had to do this for Cognizer, for both iOS and Android. I was using Unity, so they made it easy with a plugin.

Cognizer is free (no ads either), so you can download it and take a look at how that is interfaced as an example of what is acceptable. Go to the Credits screen, and click the Privacy icon in the lower left.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me what policy voilation i made? And what is this "Issue: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement"?

Comment: Out of curiosity, isn't GDPR meant to be "opt-in" ? As in, if you plan to track users, they should get a notification of what information is being sent online and why?

Comment: Good question, but I think games are covered under the cases where there's implicit consent.

https://www.itgovernance.eu/blog/en/gdpr-when-do-you-need-to-seek-consent

Comment: @ManojBalajiM You are probably not giving an option to opt out of tracking via the ID. The Unity plugin for this takes care of it.